# Intersection of polynomial subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

In space $\mathcal P_4$ there are subspaces $M=\{p\in \mathcal P_4: p(2)=0\}$and $L=\{p\in \mathcal P_4: p(3)=0\}.$
Find some base for$M\cap L$.

I understand that the polynomial in the intersection has both zero points, but I don't know how to apply my knowledge in this peculiar example.

Usually, I would take a base for one subspace and find linearly independent vectors (in respect to the base of the first subspace), construct the base for the whole vector space and after that, write the rest of the vectors from the other base as linear combinations of newly constructed base of the whole space and cut the ones from the same (second) subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors in $M \cap L$ have both 2 and 3 as roots (and those are the only conditions). Hence they must be of the form

\begin{align}
p(x) &= (x-2)(x-3)(ax^2+bx+c) \\
&= ax^2(x-2)(x-3) + bx(x-2)(x-3) + c(x-2)(x-3)\\
\end{align}

A basis would be $\{x^4-5x^3+6x^2,x^3-5x^2+6x,x^2-5x+6\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!